# CKEditor Customizing a Table

Tags: html, ckeditor

I want to generate automatically a div before every table I insert withCKEditor:

```
**<div class="cont_table">**
          <table class="mod_table">
```

Is that possible? I already added the class to the table with a CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add!

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for? http://ckeditor.com/addon/div edit; also, are you using CKEditor in a CMS or not?

Comment: I am using it inside Oracle WebCenter Sites. And No, what I'm looking for is to add that div automatically after i add a table from the toolbar icon.